Can computer components be damaged if they stay off for a long time?
I want to know if computer components can be damaged if they stay a long time off?
For example, if a good working PC stay off for some years, this can damage for example the motherboard or RAM ... or other parts?

laptop batteries...i know they shouldnt be deep discharged however i dont know how long that would take to happen

The coin cell battery backing the CMOS RAM eventually runs down, but I don't think that could be considered "damage". The environment that the parts are stored in (i.e., temperature and humidity swings) also will play into the equation.

@spuck Damage from old battery backup battery leakage is a significant problem with some old systems.

@PerdiEstaquel I have this exact question for instance with old tablets that I have lying around that seem to discharge their batteries after a week.  Should I go to the trouble of periodically charging them half full or full?

For some related answers see Will the CPU become unusable if left without power for an extended period of time?

Yes, specifically electrolytic capacitors can “deform” (basically short out) if left unpowered for a number of years (see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8794/do-electrolytic-capacitors-have-a-limited-shelf-life). These are used in power converters, primarily inside power supplies, motherboards and graphic cards.
This is primarily a problem in older and lower cost equipment.
It is also possible for flash memory chips to “decay” if left unpowered for a long period of time, especially in a hot environment. This could affect BIOS chips, SSDs and USB memory. However, I have never seen this happen.

ok , but what about for example a new mainboard that remain unsold on the store.Why it doesn't contain an "expiry" date that can alert customers for  this problem you've described ?

Capacitor aging typically takes decades.  By the time these things are issues, the "new" motherboard would be so old nobody would consider it new.  ("New old stock") Ram changes styles and goes out of production faster than these issues become a problem.

@user10489 When i say new motherboard i mean unused and remain for several years in store , and after someone that has a broken mainboard consider to buy this. It will be better to see an "expired" date so to consider to buy or not. And what about expensive motherboards that claim to have high end capacitor , are protected from these issues ?

@DonikaDonika No one is going to bother to write "best before 2070" on their packaging. Retailers have limited shelf (or warehouse) space and would likely throw away old stock to make space for new inventory that it can actually sell long before capacitor aging becomes an issue.  Unless you're buying something from the early 2000s or earlier you don't need to worry about capacitor aging (and the later part of that range is only really because of the capacitor plague).

Charge leakage in flash memory is definitely a real thing, it’s quite literally the reason that flash storage is write limited. But it also does have something to do with how many writes have happened, and the flash storage on your motherboard is not going to be written many times.

Actually, capacitor issues from devices from around 2000 are a different problem.  That's not aging, it's defective caps.  But that's a distraction from the question asked here.

"Can" and "long term" are very broad terms.  ALL electronic components will fail given enough time.  Depending on various factors such as the environment its stored in, that failure will come faster or slower.

I don't think there's anything specific to being off about electrolytic caps drying out; having the equipment powered on for the same time period would probably cause the same issues.

@Hearth This not true. Other than the rash of poorly manufactured cap some number of years ago (as mentioned above), a good quality electrolytic cap can last a long time powered but if left unpowered for a number of years will degrade. Once so degraded, careful application of voltage is required to “reform” the cap. Sudden application of full voltage to a degraded cap can cause it to explode. (See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8794/do-electrolytic-capacitors-have-a-limited-shelf-life).

@DoxyLover That's a different degradation mechanism than drying out.

@Hearth You’re right. I’ll revise my answer.

Data point: I had a motherboard from 1998 that needed its (flash) BIOS ROM chip replaced after about 20 years, since the original had become corrupt and reflashing didn't work.

I suppose the life time of devices which are dormant is much longer compared to them running continuously which is known to stress especially capacitors (especially due to the generated heat -- unsure whether storing an unpowered mainboard at 60°C would age it equally fast). The big exception are SSDs which should be powered up once a year or so.

what about solid capacitors that used on expensive motherboards ? Do they have problems like electrolytic capacitors ?

As you have addressed capacitor lifetime you may wish to add something re operational hours. || Aluminium electrolytics have rated hours (1000, 2000, more) and temperature (usually 85C or 105C). Lifetime approximately doubles per 10C so eg a 2000 hour part rated at 85C run at an average of 35C has a lifetime of ABOUT 2000 x 2^((85-35)/10)) = 2000 x 2^5 = 64000 hours or ABOUT 8 years. In hot environments a 1000 hour (usually junk) 85C part may fail earlier than is useful.

The part I would be worried about is the hard disk. I've found that dormant PCs typically have difficulty spinning up the hard drive if left idle for a while. I'm guessing that the lubricant in the bearings dries out.
Conceivably similar issues would arise regarding any CD or DVD player in the PC.
The other thing to worry about is the backup battery for the clock and possibly the BIOS memory that remembers your settings. You may find that the date and time keep resetting to 1970 or something like that, and that it forgets any settings you put into the BIOS. This battery is typically a "button" battery like the CR2032 which should be easy to replace.

Interesting. Hard drives (the ones with spinning metal) are still sold that have been produced years ago. I'd always suspect data loss on flash disks.

That's strange, I've booted up hard drives from the 2000's and never ran into that issue, If I find another ancient drive I might pay closer attention and see if it has the issue you've described.
I wasn't even aware HDD's used a liquid lubricant, I'd always assumed that any sort of contaminant that could get on the platters would be an issue.

A long long lonnng time ago I had a hard drive where the motor was accessible. Which was fortunate. On cold mornings it would not start and I had to give the motor a few persuading pushes to convince it to run. Once running it worked well. If anyone thinks that this story sounds improbably I'd agree with them. It does. BUT, it's true!

I've experienced a number of Quantum hard drives from the 90s fail in an interesting way: The rubber bumper that the head actuator "parks" against tends to dissolve into a sticky goo, and the electromagnet isn't powerful enough to pull the head arm out of the sludge it's parked against. If you had a clean room you could pry it apart and probably revive it for a little while.

I have had a number of backup disks, that by their nature are usually offline, then fail to start up when they were eventually required.

There was a particular lubricant that several major HDD manufacturers used for a while that would cause these sorts of problems. When idle and undisturbed, it would partially separate, then chemically react with moisture in the air and become viscous and goopy. Running the drive regularly masked the problem by mixing it up and preventing separation.  Thankfully, they don't use that lubricant any more.

In what years (approx) were the no-longer-functioning hard drives manufactured?  How long had they been sitting unused?

@EndAntisemiticHate I would say roughly 5 years ago (ie. 2019) and they may have been sitting unused for a year or so. I think, for example, I had a hard drive that I regularly backed up on before COVID (at a place other than my home). During COVID I was unable to go to the site and do backups. When COVID ended I found the drive, which had worked perfectly before, now did the "click of death".

I have a few older PCs at the same place which were decommissioned (because they were older and had modest amounts of RAM). About a year later when I wanted them for some not-very-taxing task, I found that some wouldn't boot at all. So, sitting around doing nothing wasn't good for them. It looked like the hard drive because I got messages about boot disk failure. Those ones might have been 10 or more years old.

Thanks for the info.  That's more recent than I expected to hear.  Were they external drives mounted inside cases, or loose "bare metal" drives?  Were they 2.5" or 3.5" (or a different size)?  Who were the manufacturer(s)? Do you know the approx avg humidity in which they were stored (likely a guesstimate, if it wasn't a highly controlled environment)?

@EndAntisemiticHate I think, but I'm not certain, that they are the Seagate 2 or 3 TB external drives (the ones that come with a wall-wart and a USB cable). Date of manufacture seems to be August 2012. They were the larger ones (3.5"). Plus some similar sized drives mounted inside old PCs, dated 2004 in one case and 2014 in another. I'm not absolutely sure which ones failed as I tend to remove them, and put them aside.

As for the humidity, some were stored in my office which was a reasonably controlled environment (but not up to "machine room" controlled level). Some were stored in an old building which would have had more temperature and humidity variation, however it was a solid brick building which would have some thermal mass. I didn't keep detailed notes about which drive failed on what day, and when it was purchased. I just have this feeling that, left alone, the chances of a hard drive failing seemed to increase somewhat.

Solid state mass storage mediums decay over time, as stated by previous answers. This has a steep temperature dependence, and in a hot environment you can expect data corruption to happen many times faster.
Some older CPUs are (to my understanding) almost eternal devices. However, the soldering that attaches dies to CPU housing, sockets to motherboards, etc, will degrade over time and eventually crack. PS3 consoles had a famous defect in them where the CPU/APU soldering turned brittle in just a few years. I remember fixing a few PS3s by reheating the motherboard with a hot air gun.
Newer CPUs will eventually be killed by background radiation and cosmic rays, but this will take decades.

"in a hot environment you can expect data corruption to happen many times faster" -- but if an SSD is stored rather than used, it would probably not be "in a hot environment" :-)

As others have pointed, electronic components do decay over time. But this time is measured in decades. The computer would be hopelessly obsolete and unfit for any useful work long before that happens.
The largest concern -- that I would not call 'damage to components' since it's not a permanent breakdown -- is that SSDs lose data if left unpowered over a very long time (several years) due to tiny sink currents in their storage cells. (For details, see The Truth About SSD Data Retention which estimates about 10 years of data retention for typical consumer use based on official JEDEC data.) I guess that this is the core reason why they are still not shipped as a PC's primary storage by default.
A small concern is the BIOS battery dying. In my practice (20+ years of adminship as of now), this only happened to some PCs before they were scrapped and also after several years. This only leads to a reset and inability to retain system BIOS settings before power cycles, of which you typically only care about the system clock (for common setups, today's PCs work fine with default BIOS settings).

What do you mean SSDs are still not shipped as the primary storage by default?  For some computers (e.g. Mac laptops) it has not been possible to even get spinning media drives for some number of years.  Also, does this mean that USB flash drives, SD cards, etc. which are less likely to be used for some years are also at a danger of losing their contents? (e.g. I have dozens of old 2GB SD cards that I would rather not have to "use" periodically to avoid losing their content, even if I have copies of it elsewhere.)

@Michael I wrote with PCs in mind. Macs are vendor-locked-in and have the intended service life of up to 7 years (https://www.macworld.com/article/673939/this-is-how-long-macs-and-macbooks-last.html), so for them, durability doesn't matter. I didn't research thumb drives since the question was about "computers"; to my knowledge, they use older, slower, less rewritable and less dense storage technology but due to the latter, retain data for much longer: it'll probably wear out sooner than it discharges.

"has little bearing on whether they are used or not." is false for electrolytic capacitors, which both degrade faster if they are used a lot (due to heat) or not at all (see Doxylover's answer). The caps in old power tools frequently explode if you put them back to use after a few years.

@PeteKirkham what about solid capacitors that used on expensive motherboards ? Do they have problems like electrolytic capacitors ?

@PeteKirkham okay, I deleted that part

"I guess that this is the core reason why they are still not shipped as a PC's primary storage by default." ← Strange thing to say. Where I'm from, for example, Dell offers most of their business laptops with a choice of SSDs as the only options.

Virtually all laptop PC's are shipped with a SSD nowadays. I checked one of the most important french online stores for hardware, and out of the 620 laptop references they have, only one has no SSD. And even the desktop PC's have almost always a SSD, sometimes with a HDD alongside.

Yes, there are various degradation processes worsening materials with time, and as the materials worsen in the computer, at a point we can say, it is off. Most other answer focus to the details of these processes. This answer focuses to their general behavior.
Most importantly, the degradation processes are faster if the PC is on as if it is off. Thus, a day of work makes it older as a day off in a dark cellar.
Second, actually the turning on/off grows a PC much more old as a long continuous work. Somewhere I have heard, a turning on/off cycle grows a PC so much older as a whole day of continuous work.
Third, components tend to die either quickly after they were started to work, or after a very, very long time (years to maybe even decades). Exactly their "planned lifetime", fe. 5 or 8 years, is the rarest.
Fourth, it is very hard to give correct numbers, even if we go into technological details (what this answer intentionally avoids). Reason is that we might see a specific component, like a hard disk, but the reality is that two hard disks from different manufacturers have nothing in common, nothing even similar, except that both answer roughly the same electric signals on its wires.
Thus, your PC might go faulty in a dark cellar after many years, but it has actually a smaller probability if you use it actively in the same years.

Mostly RAM, motherboard and other compoenents will not have a shorter lifespan due to not using them. The bios may lose its settings if the battery runs out.
You can lose data from hard drives that are made of floating-gate MOSFETs (flash memory NAND). Like SSDs or M.2.. They are progressively discharged until the information is lost.
The hard drive does not break, only the information is lost. Otherwise, the wear is not significant compared to casual use.
Regarding this, the use of HDDs is recommended to keep data on long term because they works with a disk of non magnetic material like aluminium. They can store information almost forever.
As for how long you have to leave an SSD drive unconnected for it to lose data, it depends on the technology of the drive, but I think this is off topic, if you find it interesting you can check out multi-level cell. It goes since 1-2 years on the QLC (Quad-Level Cell) to 10 years on SLC (Single-Level Cell) depends on the manufacturer.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

"an aluminum disk that is magnetized"  WTF?

@MikeB HDDs are made of a non magnetic material, e.g aluminium or glass with a magnetic coating

I think you're confused between hard drives and DRAM. There are no hard drives which use capacitor charge for storage.

Flash storage cells use floating-gate MOSFETs (aka static memory), not capacitors (aka dynamic memory).

@ivan_pozdeevthanks for the comment. I wrote capacitor for simplicity and similarity since I did not know a specific component. Answer is edited.
